# Javascript - How to sum the values in such an array?

Tags: javascript

I have such an array:

```
    let array = {
        [1]: {
          name: 'test 1',
          count: 5  
        },
        [2]: {
            name: 'test 2',
            count: 3  
        }
    }
```

How can I sum the values in the "count" column? Examples from simple arrays do not work. I currently have such a loop. Can it be done somehow better?

```
    let sum = 0
    Object.entries(array).forEach(([key, val]) => {
        sum += val.count
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `reduce`

```js
let array = { 1: { name: "test 1", count: 5, }, 2: { name: "test 2", count: 3, }, };

total = Object.values(array).reduce((t, { count }) => t + count, 0); //t accumulator accumulates the value from previous calculation 
console.log(total);
```

if you want to use a `forEach` loop like in your method use `Object.values()` instead because you only need values to calculate the sum of count

```js
let array = {
  1: { name: "test 1", count: 5 },
  2: { name: "test 2", count: 3 },
};

let sum = 0;
Object.values(array).forEach(({ count }) => {
  sum += count;
});
console.log(sum);
```

Comment: You can remove the `t =` part of the callback in the first snippet. It's not doing anything.

Comment: Yes that's true but it's just to demonstrate what the accumulator is really doing

Comment: What are you demonstrating by using unnecessary syntax and making the snippet harder to read? Its obvious that OP is new, so we don't want to introduce extra syntax if we can help it.

Answer (score 0):

*Building on top of the answer provided by @Sven.hig*

1. Since you are calling the object `"array"` you might want to use an actual array instead.
2. Creating some functions to abstract away the complexity will help you understand your code better, when you come back to it in the future.

```js
const add = (a, b) => a + b;
const sum = arr => arr.reduce(add, 0);

const data = [{
    name: "test 1",
    count: 5,
  }, {
    name: "test 2",
    count: 3,
  }
];

const total = sum(
  data.map(d => d.count)
);
console.log(total);
```